# postfix different smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter for different ISPs

Tags: postfix-mta

With this line in *postfix*'s main.cf:

```
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = xoauth2
```

I can send email through *gmail* but not through *dreamhost*.
If I delete that line I can send through *dreamhost* but not through *gmail*.

Postfix documentation for [smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter) implies I can have a *type:table* lookup for the desired mechanisms, but I'm not sure what that table should look like.  I've tried a file with a list of

```
[relayhost]:port  mech1, mech2
```

but it doesn't work. Has anyone created such a lookup table successfully?

Answer (score 0):

One answer is, courtesy of the postfix mailing list and postfix's author, to use different smtp delivery transports in master.cf, e.g:

Add to master.cf:

```
google unix - - n - - smtp
  -o smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter=xoauth2
dreamhost unix - - n - - smtp
  -o smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter=login
```

Add to main.cf:

```
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/sender_transport
```

Create sender_transport with:

```
@domain1 google:[gmail-smtp.l.google.com]:587
@domain2 dreamhost:[smtp.dreamhost.com]:587
```